# How to make a dynamic link that grabs the domain name?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a link in the phtml file

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/contact">
```

I want to write a function that would grab the value of the url and I will have something like

```
<a href="{mywebsite}/contact">
```

so if I change the domain - link will get updated automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: You need a `php` solution or `javascript`? What have you tried?

Comment: What about `<a href="/contact">`

Comment: @roa did a good example to make a relative link, if you need to show full url you can use this example: https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-php#:~:text=To%20get%20the%20current%20page,always%20available%20in%20all%20scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roa is correct. You can exclude the domain name and the uri will resolve to the current domain. Do be careful as if you exclude the leading `/` the browser will resolve as if a relative directory from the current uri. For example, the following when clicked from the root of your domain (say index.php) would resolve to the `/contacts` page. If this new page contained the same link, then pressed again it would load the `/contacts/contacts` uri. To summarize, remember your leading `/`.

`<a href="contacts">contact</a>`